# Why would a system call like clone() fail, resume, and pause?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Here is my situation: I am writing a UNIX `|` for a Operating Systems course. I finished my implementation; however, I noticed that I was non-deterministically passing test cases. The test case in question is of the form:

```
    def test_no_orphans(self):
        self.assertTrue(self.make, msg='make failed')
        subprocess.call(('strace', '-o', 'trace.log','./pipe','ls','wc','cat','cat'))
        ps = subprocess.Popen(['grep','-o','clone(','trace.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out1 = subprocess.check_output(('wc','-l'), stdin=ps.stdout)
        ps.wait()        
        ps.stdout.close()
        ps = subprocess.Popen(['grep','-o','wait','trace.log'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        out2 = subprocess.check_output(('wc','-l'), stdin=ps.stdout)
        ps.wait()  
        ps.stdout.close()
        out1 = int(out1.decode("utf-8")[0])
        out2 = int(out2.decode("utf-8")[0])
        if out1 == out2 or out1 < out2:
            orphan_check = True
        else:
            orphan_check = False
        self.assertTrue(orphan_check, msg="Found orphan processes")
        subprocess.call(['rm', 'trace.log'])
        self.assertTrue(self._make_clean, msg='make clean failed')
```

After inspecting the relevant log, I find that:

```
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f04174ad850) = 1330
close(4)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1330, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
pipe([4, 5])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f04174ad850) = 1331
close(5)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
pipe([3, 5])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f04174ad850) = ? ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1331, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f04174ad850) = 1332
close(5)                                = 0
--- SIGCHLD {si_signo=SIGCHLD, si_code=CLD_EXITED, si_pid=1332, si_uid=1000, si_status=0, si_utime=0, si_stime=0} ---
close(4)                                = 0
pipe([4, 5])                            = 0
clone(child_stack=NULL, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x7f04174ad850) = 1333
```

specifically, the line with `ERESTARTNOINTR (To be restarted)` is causing me to fail. I reported this to the TA in charge of the assignment after my professor helped me debug and said it is possibly a bug in the test cases.

I was wondering why exactly `clone()` could fail, as it seems like `fork()` handles this in a nice C wrapper for us. I was also wondering what specifically is happening here, and also why it seems that system calls in general seem to have an `incomplete` and a `resumed` state, as my OS professor said he doesn't know too much about it, and he basically said it could be "race conditions in the kernel".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The man page for `clone(2)` says that `ERESTARTNOINTR` is returned when

> System call was interrupted by a signal and will be restarted.  (This can be seen only during a trace.)

The failing `clone` syscall in the provided log was interrupted by the `SIGCHLD` signal for pid 1331.

Comment: How about when I see something like `resumed` or `unfinished`?

Comment: That occurs when another thread or process makes a syscall while an existing syscall is still being executed (often one like `read` or `select`). See the `strace(1)` man page for lots more details.

Comment: Why exactly would a SIGCHILD force the `clone()` to restart? Isn't the purpose of a `fork()` to handle that?

Comment: According to the patch that added that line to the manpage (https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-man/msg10249.html), `clone` and `fork` will return `ERESTARTNOINTR` if they're interrupted by a signal before the new process gets added to its process group (i.e. while the parent process is copying itself, but before the child is started).

Comment: Got it. Thank you. I'll accept your answer. Could you tell me how you found that patch information?

Comment: I got there from https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1330661, which I found a ways down the google results for "clone erestartnointr".

Comment: Why is this something that would want to happen by the way? Is it just so that the kernel calls the appropriate signal handler in a timely fashion, if any exists?

Comment: @user129393192 It's a quirk in the Unix/Linux signal design. If a signal happens while a system call is happening, the system call has to return, so it returns error EINTR or something like that, and then you're supposed to make the same call again. Often this is hidden from you because the C library will just make the same system call again. I would say it is a bug in the test case - unless there's some reason why you should not be allowed to get SIGCHLD at this particular moment.

Comment: @user129393192 and resumed/unfinished happens when strace prints one system call while another one is still happening. This only happens in multithreaded scenarios or when strace traces more than one process. It prints something like `call1(....unfinished` `call2()` `...resuming call1)`. This is purely related to how strace displays the calls, it is not a special thing that happens to the actual calls